# Debian Wheezy - Some Websites Not Loading

Tags: networking, debian, browser, debian-wheezy

I just upgraded from Debian Etch to Wheezy 7.3. Things seemed to go fine but I can't load half of the websites I usually go to any more.

I thought it may be an IPv6 issue so I disabled it but the problem remains. The websites that I can't open will open on my other computers which are connected to the same router in the same fashion.

I get no error message other than "webpage is not available". I have tried Chrome, Epiphany and Iceweasel will all the same results.

Could someone suggest what happened to my settings that would just block some websites??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping these sites?

Comment: Can these sites resolve DNS?

Comment: Ping is acting very strange. I can't ping google.com or any other website. but I can load up google and do searches just fine. however a lot of websites that i have confirmed working will just not load. and no error is given other than it can't be reached.

Comment: how do i know / check if a website can resolve DNS?

Comment: Also, I can ping my loop back address but not my router.

Comment: Although I can not ping my router I can log into through the web browser.

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf shows nameserver 127.0.0.1   that doesn't seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

resolved the problem

needed to modify the resolv.conf file. it only had the loop back address. I manually added the DNS server IP addresses and now it works. What a headache that was!